# Upload files and subfolders in defined order through SFTP using WinSCP (put command)

Tags: sftp, winscp

I have a folder (Source) that contains subfolders and XML files:

```
Source\
    Folder1\
    Folder2\
    Folder1.xml
    Folder2.xml
```

I need to transfer these subfolders and files through SFTP using WinSCP but my constraint is that I need to transfer the subfolders first and only at the end the remaining files.

I can use the `put` command, but it seems that if I use wildcard it copies everything.

I.e:

```
put \\Sharepath\Source\*
```

Using the Windows scripting it works fine, but it seems that I can't do the same thing using `put` command

I.e:

```vb
'Copy only folders
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFolder \\\SharePath\Source\*, \\\SharePath\Destination, True

'Copy only files
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFiles \\\SharePath\Source\*.xml, \\\SharePath\Destination\, True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WinSCP `put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) twice:

- first to upload only the subfolders by excluding the `*.xml` files using a filemask:

  ```
  put \\Sharepath\Source\* -filemask=|*.xml
  ```

  See
  https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask
  https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#filemask
- second, to upload the `.xml files:

  ```
  put \\Sharepath\Source\*.xml
  ```

Comment: Thank you! You are a genius! I have just tested and it works! I am ashamed as I have read the documentation all morning on winscp but I think I missed that part.